# Escape $ (dollar) into bash command in docker compose is not interpreted

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I would need some help with docker compose and the $ caracter.

Here an example of container in docker compose :

```
services:
  setup: 
    image: image:tag
    container_name: setup
    user: "0"
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c '
        sed -i 's/before with a $$/after with a $$/' /foo/bar/something.txt;
      '
```

When I try with this, the sed command goes without any $, even if I escaped it twice. What am I missing?

Best regards,

On the docker compose side, I see there is no other way to escape the $ caracter : I have to double-it with another $ : $$

However, in the bash command, no $ is interpreted, so the sed command doesn't work

Comment: Can you write this into an entrypoint wrapper script that runs at container startup time?  That would save you multiple levels of escapind here.  (It's worth noting that this `command:` runs _instead of_ the image's `CMD`, so this container as you've shown it will run the `sed` command and then exit immediately, and the changes to the container's local filesystem will be lost.)

Comment: It may be relevant to know that docker-compose and single quotes don't always mix; per the documentation: `single quotes will take the string as is without unpacking the variable’s value.` I bet the double dollar sign is only parsed into a dollar sign literal if the command is wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Thanks David Maze for you quick answer However, I prefer use the command instead of the entrypoint because I don't want it to be executed before the container is up.